# Smart way to access deeply nested DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath

I'm about to write an extension for Google Chrome Browser. It's a content script which changes the width of a table. This is the XPath for the mentioned table:

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]

/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]/fieldset/div[1]/div[2]
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]/fieldset/div[2]/div[2]
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]/fieldset/div[3]/div[2]
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible to access the table with *getElementById*, *getElementsByName* or similar. I found the following solution:

```
document.getElement("body").childNodes[7].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[3].childNodes[9].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[5].width=500

document.getElement("body").childNodes[7].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[3].childNodes[9].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[5].childNodes[3].childNodes[3].childNodes[3].style.width="300px"
document.getElement("body").childNodes[7].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[3].childNodes[9].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[5].childNodes[3].childNodes[7].childNodes[3].style.width="300px"
document.getElement("body").childNodes[7].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[3].childNodes[9].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[5].childNodes[3].childNodes[5].childNodes[3].style.width="350px"
```

Although this solution works, I'm not satisfied with it. Is there a smarter way to do that?

Comment: I believe that can be done with an [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)/:nth-of-type query and a modern CSS selector engine (such as Sizzle found in jQuery or [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome supports the <kbd>[`document.evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.evaluate)</kbd> function which can select elements by XPath.

The signature:

```
var xpathResult = document.evaluate(
 xpathExpression, 
 contextNode, 
 namespaceResolver, 
 resultType, 
 result
);
```

In your case this will be

```
var expr = "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]";
var td = document.evaluate(expr, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
```

You can also use `XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE` to get a list of nodes through an iterator.

*Edit:* You can also use the transform the XPath to a CSS3 selector and use `document.querySelector`:

```
var expr = "body > table > tbody > tr > td > table:nth-of-type(2) > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(3)";
var td = document.querySelector(expr);
```